# Recreate bounce easing with spring easing

Tags: javascript, bounce, easing-functions, velocity.js

Looking through velocity.js changelog I read:

> ... 2) The back, bounce, and elastic easings have been removed. Use
>   spring physics instead. ...

I was wondering if there is any simple way to recreate the `easeOutBounce` effect that is available with jQuery animate using the `spring` easing, that accepts custom parameters?

By default you can use the `spring` easing as following:

```
$('.ball').velocity({ top: ['200px', 'spring']}, { duration: 2000 });
```

The spring easing **can be customized** by specifying `[tension, friction]` instead of passing just the easing keyword `spring`. So you can do:

```
$('.ball').velocity({ top: ['200px', [500, 0]]}, { duration: 2000 });
```

I'm failing to understand which values of friction and tension to use in order to achieve a [easeOutBounce easing](http://easings.net/#easeOutBounce). I'm trying to make the ball bounce when it reaches 200px - but instead it acts as a "loose" spring, going below the ground line instead of bouncing.

**Is this possible to do in a simple way with velocity.js only**, so I don't need to implement custom easing functions by myself?

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
   $('.ball').css('top', '120px');
   $('.ball').velocity({ top: ['200px', [500, 0]]}, { duration: 2000 });
});
```

```css
.display {
  width: 240px;
  height: 280px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.ball {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.ball:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.ground {
  position: absolute;
  top: 220px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.1.0/velocity.min.js"></script>

<button>Throw ball</button>
<div class="display">
  <div class="ball"></div>
  <div class="ground"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being the guy that helped creating that easing in Velocity, I understand it's not possible to create bounce and elastic easings with it. But if you'll ask Julian (creator of Velocity) he'll probably say you're better off with a spring easing than with bounce.

Having said that, your best bet is to register these easings yourself on Velocity. Check out explanations at the bottom of [this thread](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/issues/283).

Comment: Thanks for the info - that is exactly what I've ended up doing - using the jQuery UI bounce and extended it into velocity. I just got confused since the changelog was kinda written like spring with custom parameters substitutes bounce effect - which it does not since the physics are different.